# aspx ajax control toolkit rating

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/rating/rating.aspx

can i somehow disable clicking on stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ReadOnly attribute you can set.  From your link:

ReadOnly - Whether or not the rating can be changed